# How to Insert A Non-String Object as a Key in Database

Tags: python, mongodb, key

right now I am using **mongoDB** and faces key error based on the datatype restriction to "String" only.

> InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was ('good', 'beneficial')

The action I had tried is following:

#### 1) Create a database named in 'glot'

#### 2) Make a collection with name "usr_history"

#### 3) Try to insert a usr_history document into the collection

with following command in jupyter-notebook

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient() #to run the mongod instance we need a client to run it

db = client['glot'] #we connect to 'test-database' with the pre-defined client instance

collection = db['usr_history']

edge_attr = {('good','beneficial'):"good is beneficial", ('beneficial','supportive'):"beneficial means something supportive"} #create this with glat_algo

usr_history = {"nodes": ['good', 'beneficial', 'supportive'], "edges": [('good', 'beneficial'), ('beneficial', 'supportive')], "rephrase": edge_attr}

collection.insert_one(usr_history)
```

and the last command returns error as the above mentioned.

Basically what I am trying to do is to store the (vertex, edge, edge_attr) data into **any** DB so that I can keep tracking of larage amount of usr_history data for analyzing those using python.

I am not confined to mongoDB, so you can give me a guideline or solution not just with mongoDB, but with another alternatives.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In MongoDB the keys are in string format. For example `"1"` is valid key, but `1` is not. I tried to have "numbered columns" in MySQL and that did not bode well, when indexing trough the table. So try to avoid that naming convention for keys in any database. Values can be in number format ( `"mykey" = 1` and `"mykeys" = [1,2,3]` are valid).

Comment: @Mika72 thx. literally my first time to see the new word bode.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a non-string value as a key; only strings can be keys.

It will work better if you store `('good','beneficial')` as the value of a separate attribute, perhaps like this:

```js
edge_attr = [
  {"attr" : ('good','beneficial'), "val" : "good is beneficial"}, 
  {"attr" : ('beneficial','supportive'), "val" : "beneficial means something supportive"}
];
```